# Want to capture browser and environment details in Extent report when executed parallely on different devices

Tags: testng, cucumber-jvm, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I have designed a automation framework using cucumber java with testng and Extent report. I run a single feature file on multiple environments using browser stack, i want to capture the browser and environment information for each of the scenario executed on extent report, so that i get to know on which specific browser the feature is failing.

Attaching the screen shot for what i am looking out for.

Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Get them before test case execution and write the details on tests as debug steps.

```
    public static String getBrowser() {
    Log.info("Getting system browser name . . .");
    Capabilities cap = ((RemoteWebDriver) getDriver()).getCapabilities();
    String browserName = cap.getBrowserName().toLowerCase();
    return StringUtils.capitalize(browserName);
    }

    public static String getVersion() {
    Log.info("Getting browser version . . .");
    Capabilities cap = ((RemoteWebDriver) getDriver()).getCapabilities();
    String v = cap.getVersion().toString();
    Log.info("Browser version: " + v);
    return v;
    }
```

To add the data onTestStart add:

```
extentTest.debug(MarkupHelper.createLabel(getBrowser() + " " + getVersion(), ExtentColor.TRANSPARENT));
```

Comment: Excellent answer

Comment: @Neagu You need to update your solution as OP required it in Title Section, Where your Syntax says it will add in regular Log Section.

Answer (score 2):

You have to get Browser information and System Environment information first and then you need to pass it to Extent Report while create test.

**To get Environment details of System :**

This is Sample example for Windows System Commands:

```
    String nameOS = "os.name";
    String versionOS = "os.version";
    String architectureOS = "os.arch";

    nameOS = System.getProperty(nameOS);
    versionOS = System.getProperty(versionOS);
    architectureOS = System.getProperty(architectureOS);

    System.out.println("The information about OS");
    System.out.println("Name of the OS: " + nameOS);
    System.out.println("Version of the OS: " + versionOS);
    System.out.println("Architecture of THe OS: " + architectureOS);

    Output will be as according to your System Arch like:
    -----------------------------------------------------
    The information about OS
    Name of the OS: Windows 10
    Version of the OS: 10.0
    Architecture of THe OS: amd64
```

*You can retrieve Environment details, Which you need. You may refer this Blog link for specific System Commands. [Click Here](http://%20https://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/OSInformation.shtml)*

**To get Browser details :**

```
Capabilities browserCap = ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities();
String browserName = browserCap.getBrowserName();
String browserVersion = browserCap.getVersion();
```

Now, You need this details to add in ExtentReport Title Section, You can do By using:

**Solution :**

```
ExtentTest testlog;
//extentReport is object of ExtentReport class

testlog= extentReport.createTest("This is Title Section", "This is Description Section<br />" + "OS:"+nameOS + " <br /> Browser Name: "+browserName);
```

like wise, You add multiple Strings in to Description section which you need. All you can capture it by `createTest()` method.